# nginx wordpress upload size sites enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am using [EasyEngine](https://github.com/rtCamp/easyengine) on an Ubuntu server. I need to be able to set the upload size for the WP media library on an individual site located on a server with multiple sites. I don't want to edit php.ini or the default nginx configuration because I just want to change the settings for one site.

I found [this documentation](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-file-upload-size-limit/) on the rtCamp site, but adding `client_max_body_size` to the `sites-enabled/` file didn't work:

```
server {

    ...

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    ...

}
```

The WordPress Media Library still says "Maximum upload file size: 100 MB."

Is there a way to accomplish this via `wp-config.php` or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ini_set` php method for the same purpose. Add following line to the top of the page where this upload script is written:

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","#SIZE#");
```

Replace `#SIZE#` with the actual size you want max file size limit while uploading.

Comment: The upload script is written in some `wp-admin/` file I believe. I can't place it there or it will be wiped out when WP core updates.

I tried adding it to `functions.php` in my theme directory but it didn't work. Maybe there's a WP filter/action I could use?

Comment: May be adding following line to your .heaccess will work: php_value upload_max_filesize #SIZE# Replace #SIZE# with actual size.

Comment: Nginx doesn't use .htaccess.